# Insurance company Call To Action "Buy online" vs "Get a free quote"

Tags: buttons

I'm currently working on the redesign of an insurance company website.
So for the main call to action I use the copy "Get a free quote” With a link on the button to go to the online quote process with at the end the possibility to buy it. This flow makes perfect sens to me. Nobody wants to buy something if you don't know the price.. The rest of the industry is doing the same thing (see visual below).

But the CEO of the company is stubborn and doesn’t want to reason and because he wants people to buy online he want a "Buy Online" button…

I'm trying to find some studies or stats to push my point. To sell more you need to start by a free quote.

Any thoughts for helping me?

**Get a quote examples:**

[image: get a quote example]

Comment: UX isn't about choosing a point and then finding data to back up that point.  It's about making a hypothesis and then finding out whether your hypothesis is correct or not by looking at all the data - not just the data that supports your position.  Essentially it's using the scientific method.

Comment: "Get a quote" implies to me that pricing is variable. "Buy online" suggests flat rates, like $500k coverage costs $50/mo., regardless of factors like age or history.

Answer (score 2):

You could A/B test it to see what actually happens...

Or you could point your boss at some existing 'Behavioural Economics' research:

http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2011/05/how-the-power-of-free-and-scarcity-influence-decision-making.php

*Dan Ariely, in his book Predictably Irrational, says free ”is an emotional hot button—a source of irrational excitement.” Ariely and his colleagues have conducted some interesting experiments to learn about the power of free. In one experiment, they offered people a choice between a Hershey’s kiss priced at 1 cent or a Lindt truffle priced at 15 cents. Which type of chocolate do you think sold better?*

*Not surprisingly, the Lindt chocolate sold better; 73% of purchasers bought the Lindt. But then, the researchers ran another round of the experiment during which they offered the same choices—except they reduced the price of each type of chocolate by just one cent. Now the Hershey’s kiss was free, and the Lindt truffle was 14 cents. Which do you think sold better?*

*Even though they reduced the price by only one cent, there was a dramatic shift in behavior. In this second round of the experiment, 69% of the people favored the free Hershey’s kiss over the Lindt truffle.*

Comment: +1 for suggesting A/B testing, this should be easy to test and measure.

Answer (score 1):

### Buttons should always start with a Verb

Let's begin where both options agree.  Buttons that start with a Verb improve the user/computer interaction over a text description followed by an OK button.

The problem here is that the verb your boss *hopes* users will perform -- "Buy" -- isn't what actually happens when the button is clicked.

Would you use a button named "Delete pictures online" to show a list of pictures that can eventually be deleted?

Adding a button that says "Buy" is a barrier to entry just like adding a button on the home page that says "Delete" it's not worth the risk of clicking it so users will just go somewhere else.

**Verbs need to exactly describe the action that will be performed when the button is clicked.**

### User Testing

Asking your users which they prefer is one way to settle the disagreement.  It does, however, look like you did some exploratory research already on your own and found the answer most people in the space determined was the best.

### Tracking Metrics

Large companies track changes in conversion rate data but don't normally share it.  If they are all ending up with a call to action button that says "Get a Quote" then it is most likely working better than anything else they tried.

It is possible that none of them ever tried "Buy Online" so you could always use that for a little while and then change it and compare conversion rates.

---

#### Here's a crazy idea that just might work...

Note: this would require a bit of usability testing because this approach is quite different.

I think it is safe to assume that people are on your page to "Buy insurance online" so what if you simply started with a quote and then let people do things to try and make it lower?

`There are a lot of factors that determine monthly insurance rates.`

`Right now, our cheapest policy is $80 per month and our highest policy is $5422 per month.`

`Fill in the fields below to see your monthly quote.`

Comment: Great idea on the range presentation. As someone who's worked in those big testing environments, DaveAlger is absolutely right: if they're all going in one direction, they probably have data to prove it. But you won't find that data posted publicly. Tell the CEO that market evidence suggests that an a/b test is in order. If that doesn't work, give up and move on. < Speaking from experience there ;)

Comment: [WhichTestWon](https://whichtestwon.com/case-studies/) is a good resource to help stubborn clients / sponsors see the value in confirming assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

"Get a Free Quote" and "Buy Online" are absolutely different things, so can't even imagine how is it up for discussion. Anyways, the point is: is this button going to be used to complete a **BUY** action or just to **GET A QUOTE**? There you have the first part of the answer. Once you define what action do you want to perform, you can worry about wording. If you don't even know that first, whatever wording you use will be random at best.

Once you define that, a good approach is **ACTION+BENEFIT+TIME**, like *"Save 10% Now!"* or something like that. You can (and should) test it, but if wording is your concern, something like this will get mad clicks vs "get a free quote" or "buy online". But you gotta TEST, TEST, TEST.